# Running Get-WinEvent with hashfilter from directory - exeption in some cases

Tags: powershell, event-log

when running

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="U:\test\SavedSecurity.evtx";ID="4624";}
```

with no admin-rights everything works fine.

Even

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="U:\test\SavedSecurity.evtx";}
```

with no filters works fine.

But running

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="U:\test\SavedSecurity.evtx";ProviderName="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing";ID="4624";}
```

fails with `UnauthorizedAccessException?`

I cannot filter via ProviderName without being admin, but can read all events as big list?

What I'm trying to do is: filter all logon-logoff events from several eventlogs (in one folder) with information, if the login was local or remote and export them to a CSV. I cannot use `Get-Event` because it cannot handle events from custom-paths somewhere on the disk. To get closer I split everything to figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your last example is wrong. Either search in a file given by path or search in data given by a provider.

You tried to access data in different ways with differents access rights (Path vs. Provider). In one case you are searching in a file you are owning (exported Log file). In this case you have sufficient rights. But you have possibly no right to search in data given by provider Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing. You need Admin rights to do the latter. There is no workaround.